# How to remove/replace "sys.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY" in result set in Oracle?

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I built this query -

```
SELECT Trim(owner_dsply_nm)                  AS CASE_OWNER 
           ,count(distinct case_intrl_id)        AS NUMBER_OF_CASES_WORKED
           ,cast(collect(distinct case_intrl_id) AS sys.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY) AS CASE_ID 
           ,Trim(status_nm)                      AS STATUS_VALUE 
           ,To_char(action_ts, 'MON.DD.YYYY')    AS STATUS_CHANGE_DATE 
           ,To_char(action_ts - 7 / 24, 'IYYY')  AS STATUS_CHANGE_YEAR 
           ,To_char(action_ts - 7 / 24, 'IW')    AS STATUS_CHANGE_WEEK 
      FROM KDD_CASE_ACTIONS a 
           join KDD_STATUS s 
             ON a.status_cd = s.status_cd 
           join KDD_REVIEW_OWNER r 
             ON r.owner_seq_id = a.action_by_id 
     WHERE a.status_cd NOT IN ( 'SBTMNEW', 'NW', 'SB01NEW' ) 
     AND Trim(UPPER(owner_dsply_nm)) NOT IN ('SYSTEM')
     GROUP BY Trim(owner_dsply_nm) 
              ,Trim(status_nm) 
              ,To_char(action_ts, 'MON.DD.YYYY') 
              ,To_char(action_ts - 7 / 24, 'IYYY') 
              ,To_char(action_ts - 7 / 24, 'IW')
```

[image: Result]

I want to remove/hide "SYS.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY" from the result set. What can I try further in my query?

Comment: What you're seeing in your output is SQL Developer's built-in string representation of User Defined Types. Your `CASE_ID` column is actually a `VARRAY`, so you'll have to write a function to display it as a VARCHAR2 if you want to change its appearance. Personally I would use LISTAGG instead of COLLECT + CAST.

Comment: @kfinity - Thank you for your suggestion. I tried LISTAGG but then it has hard limit of 4000 char. Hence I used array function.

Comment: Using `(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,case_intrl_id,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY case_intrl_id).GetClobVal(),',')) AS CASE_ID` solved my issue but then I am not getting distinct values of `case_intrl_id` :-(

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by replacing `sys.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY` by `XMLAGG` and applied `regexp_replace` on it.

```
SELECT Trim(owner_dsply_nm)                  AS CASE_OWNER 
       ,count(distinct case_intrl_id)        AS NUMBER_OF_CASES_WORKED
       --,cast(collect(distinct case_intrl_id) AS sys.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY)  AS CASE_ID  
       ,regexp_replace((RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,case_intrl_id,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY case_intrl_id).GetClobVal(),',')),'([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1') AS CASE_ID
       ,Trim(status_nm)                      AS STATUS_VALUE 
       ,To_char(action_ts, 'MON.DD.YYYY')    AS STATUS_CHANGE_DATE 
       ,To_char(action_ts - 7 / 24, 'IYYY')  AS STATUS_CHANGE_YEAR 
       ,To_char(action_ts - 7 / 24, 'IW')    AS STATUS_CHANGE_WEEK 
FROM KDD_CASE_ACTIONS a
       join KDD_STATUS s 
         ON a.status_cd = s.status_cd 
       join KDD_REVIEW_OWNER r 
         ON r.owner_seq_id = a.action_by_id 
 WHERE a.status_cd NOT IN ( 'SBTMNEW', 'NW', 'SB01NEW' ) 
 AND Trim(UPPER(owner_dsply_nm)) NOT IN ('SYSTEM')
 GROUP BY Trim(owner_dsply_nm) 
          ,Trim(status_nm) 
          ,To_char(action_ts, 'MON.DD.YYYY') 
          ,To_char(action_ts - 7 / 24, 'IYYY') 
          ,To_char(action_ts - 7 / 24, 'IW') 
 ORDER BY STATUS_CHANGE_YEAR DESC 
          ,STATUS_CHANGE_WEEK DESC 
          ,CASE_OWNER;
```